# To extract data out of tables without specifec sector and dates?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The one requirement i have is where it says

```
and stock_info_copy.stock in  (36 ,2478)    
and stock_info_copy.year > 1987
```

IF stock is 2478 i should only get values > 1997 but I need 36 from the beginning for the whole period (1989-1996 and after)

The table is as follows:
[image]

I have tried the following query but didn't get good results:

```
select stock_info_copy.stock, stock_category.category, stock_type.type,     stock_info_copy.year, stock_info_copy.month, stock_info_copy.prev_price,     stock_info_copy.prev_quantity, stock_info_copy.price, stock_info_copy.dividend,     stock_info_copy.day, stock_info_copy.price_return, stock_info_copy.dividend_return    
from stock_info_copy, stock, notation, stock_category, stock_type    
where stock_category.stock = stock.ID    
and notation.ID = stock_info_copy.stock    
and stock_info_copy.stock = stock.ID        
and stock_type.stock = stock.ID    
and stock.sharetype = 1    
and stock.stockexchange = 1    
and stock_type.type in ( 10,11, 16,17,18,19)    
and stock_category.category < 2000    
and notation.sector > 1    
and stock_info_copy.stock in  (36 ,2478)    
and stock_info_copy.year > 1987
and stock_info_copy.year < 2013
and
(
(
(notation.sector <> 78 and year <  1989 and stock_info_copy.stock not in (select stock from notation where notation.sector=78))
or
(notation.sector <> 78 and year  = 1989 and month <= 11 and stock_info_copy.stock not in (select stock from notation where notation.sector=78))
or
(
notation.sector <> 78 and notation.sector <> 291
and notation.sector <> 292 and notation.sector <> 293 and notation.sector <> 295    
and notation.sector <> 296 and notation.sector <> 297 and notation.sector <> 298     
and stock_info_copy.stock not in (select stock from notation where notation.sector in (291, 292,293,295,78,296,297,298))    
and (year > 1989 or (year = 1989 and month >=11))    
and (year < 1996 or (year = 1996 and month < 5))    
)  

or   

(    
(    
year = 1996 and month > 5) or year > 1996)    

)     
)         

order by stock_info_copy.stock, stock_info_copy.year, stock_info_copy.month
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example says 1987 but your words say 1997.  I'll assume the latter.

The `WHERE` clause should read, in part,

```
and (
        (stock_info_copy.stock = 2478
        and stock_info_copy.year > 1997)
    or
        (stock_info_copy.stock = 36)
    )
```